# Counting letters in line from file but excluding special characters

Tags: c

My program count letters but it did'n count it well. It should count amount of letters in every single line in file.
Source code:

```
FILE *fp;
int     i, 
    counter;    // Liczba liter w wiadomosci
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF-8");

while(run)
{
    fp = fopen(FIFO, "r");
    fwide(fp, 1);
    while ((line = fgetws(buffer, sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0], fp)) != NULL) 
    {
          counter = 0;
          for (i = 0; line[i] != L'\0'; i++)
              if (iswalpha(line[i]))
                 counter++;

          printf("Amount of letters: %d", counter);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

When in file is specific symbol end of the line '\0' it doesn't count properly. For example if file i got line: qwerty \00 azerty and it return only amount of 6 not 12.
How can i fix it ?

Comment: Do the letters you need from your file are supposed to be encoded in multi-byte format or is the file being read just a standard text file?

Answer (score 0):

Read the results into a buffer using `read(3)` (or `fread(3)`):

```
size_t nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer), sizeof(*buffer), fp);
```

then, assuming you want line-by-line numbers:

```
for (wchar_t *bp = buffer, *ep = buffer + nread; bp < ep; bp++) {
    /* look for end-of-line character */
    wchar_t *eol = wmemchr(bp, L'\n', ep - bp);
    size_t n;

    if (eol == NULL) {
        /* now what? count the characters till the end of the buffer? */
        ...
    }

    /* the subarray from BP to EOL is one line, do the counting */
    n = count(bp, eol - bp);
    printf("Amount of letters: %zu\n", n);

    /* set bp to eol for the next iteration */
    bp = eol;
}
```

All the code for counting is now in:

```
size_t count(const wchar_t *line, size_t ncharacters)
{
    size_t counter = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ncharacters; i++) {
        if (iswalpha(line[i])) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Of course this codes lacks error-checking, like when `eol` is NULL because there aren't any newline characters in the buffer.  Also, you may have to loop over the `fread(3)` bit because `fread(3)` may return less items than your buffer can account for, for instance because of non-blocking I/O or simply because there aren't more characters available at the moment.

Comment: it doesn't work. What i should write in if(eol == NULL) ??

Comment: I don't know the exact purpose, do you want to count letters per line?  Then what is a line, a string ending in `\n`? In this case you'd simply write `break;`